# Do I have to retrieve twice to save one-to-one association using spring mvc?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a situation in my application, it resembles like below.

```
Entity1 : Employee
Entity2: Employer.
```

Both above entity has one to many relation. One employer has many employee. I have prepared a spring mvc form. In that form, I have retrieved employer id and name and loaded into the `<select>` tag.

Now, if I put a employee name in the text field. And select one employer in the dropdown.

If I click submit, spring mvc will give employee name and employer id.

Now, to store the employee into the database, do I have retrieve the employer object one more time using the ID i got from the form?

Comment: It really depends on your mappings.  Can you share your Employer & Employee mappings, whether it be classes with annotations or xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to have a reference to the employer in order to set the employer of the new employee.

Either use `em.find()` to get it from the database and make sure it exists: that will execute a SQL query to find the employer by its ID.

Or use `em.getReference()` to get a lazy-loaded proxy over the employer, without executing any query, assuming that it exists in the database. That will of course fail with an exception when inserting the employee if the employer doesn't actually exist (if you have a foreign key constraint. If you don't: your employee will refer to a non-existing employer).

Comment: Thank you. I think I got it